# Prevent runtime panic in bson.ObjectIdHex

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

i'm trying to convert string of objectid to bson ObjectId format with mgo,

`errCheck := d.C("col").FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(obid[0])).One(&Result)`

idk why, but if i give a wrong / invalid input string, my application got runtime panic

how i can prevent that ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bson.ObjectIdHex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#ObjectIdHex) documents that it will panic if you pass an invalid object id:

> ObjectIdHex returns an ObjectId from the provided hex representation. **Calling this function with an invalid hex representation will cause a runtime panic.** See the IsObjectIdHex function.

If you want to avoid this, first check your input string using [`bson.IsObjectIdHex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#IsObjectIdHex), and only proceed to call `bson.ObjectIdHex()` if your input is valid:

```
if bson.IsObjectIdHex(obid[0]) {
    // It's valid, calling bson.ObjectIdHex() will not panic...
}
```

Comment: Why do I get with `bson.ObjectIdHex` error `undefined: bson.ObjectIdHex`

Answer (score 0):

As @icza said in the last answer. you should check validity if ObjectId. 
And you can use [panic recover defer](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)  to handle any kind of error in future

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := Result{}
    getData(&r)
}

func IdentifyPanic() string {
    var name, file string
    var line int
    var pc [16]uintptr

    n := runtime.Callers(3, pc[:])
    for _, pc := range pc[:n] {
        fn := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
        if fn == nil {
            continue
        }
        file, line = fn.FileLine(pc)
        name = fn.Name()

        if !strings.HasPrefix(name, "runtime.") {
            break
        }
    }
    file = filepath.Base(file)

    switch {
    case name != "":
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", file, line)
    case file != "":
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", file, line)
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("pc:%x", pc)
}

type Result struct {
    success int
    data string
}
func getData(result *Result){
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            ip := IdentifyPanic()
            errorMessage := fmt.Sprintf("%s Error: %s", ip, err)
            fmt.Println(errorMessage)
            result.success = 0
        }
    }()
    if bson.IsObjectIdHex(obid[0]) {                                 // this line copied from @icza answer
        // It's valid, calling bson.ObjectIdHex() will not panic...  // this line copied from @icza answer
        errCheck := d.C("col").FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(obid[0])).One(&res)
        result.success = 1
        result.data = "your result (res). this is just the exam"
    }else{
        result.success = 0  
    }
}
```

Comment: this is right answer too, but more complex, thank you !