# How Find function's generic map was created?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am looking at this example.
 I would never coome up with solution like this,I would go for bson.raw.

```
type Movie struct {
    ID        bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name      string        `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Year      string        `json:"year" bson:"year"`
    Directors []string      `json:"directors" bson:"directors"`
    Writers   []string      `json:"writers" bson:"writers"`
    BoxOffice BoxOffice     `json:"boxOffice" bson:"boxOffice"`
}
```

GetMovie function reads data from MongoDB and returns JSON

```
func (db *DB) GetMovie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    var movie Movie
    err := db.collection.Find(bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(vars["id"])}).One(&movie)
    if err != nil {
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    } else {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        response, _ := json.Marshal(movie)
        w.Write(response)
    }

}
```

I do not understand how generic map bson.M was created. Why did the author used `bson.ObjectIdHex(vars["id"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#M) is a map under the hood:

```
type M map[string]interface{}
```

And this:

```
bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(vars["id"])}
```

Is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) creating a value of type `bson.M`. It has a single pair where key is `"_id"` and the associated value is a [`bson.ObjectId`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#ObjectId) returned by the function [`bson.ObjectIdHex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#ObjectIdHex).

The document ID to look up and return is most likely coming as a hexadecimal string in `vars["id"]`, and `bson.ObjectIdHex()` converts (parses) this into an `ObjectId`.

Tips: to query a document by ID, easier is to use [`Collection.FindId`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.FindId), e.g.:

```
err := db.collection.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(vars["id"])).One(&movie)
```

Also to avoid a runtime panic in case an invalid ID is stored in `vars["id"]`, you could use [`bson.IsObjectIdHex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#IsObjectIdHex) to check it first. For details, see [Prevent runtime panic in bson.ObjectIdHex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701764/prevent-runtime-panic-in-bson-objectidhex/53701933#53701933).

Also, marshaling the result into a byte slice and then writing it to the response is inefficient, the response could be streamed to the output using [`json.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder). For details, see [Ouput json to http.ResponseWriter with template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021403/ouput-json-to-http-responsewriter-with-template/55021498#55021498).