# mgo is setting objectid to objectidhex, which doesnt seem to get read by Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo, mongo-go

I am trying to make a query using the ObjectId, and normally in mongodb you would do something like this

```
db.collection.findOne({"_id":objectid("5d9d90e5ed645489aae6df64")})
```

Which this works when I do a normal query but in go lang it gives it the value of

```
ObjectIdHex("5d9d90e5ed645489aae6df64")
```

instead which does not lead to a valid query.

i have read through the mgo documentation many times trying to use

```
bson.ObjectId("5d9d90e5ed645489aae6df64")
```

but it still makes it a hex which I don't understand. I have tried a few different combination of things with no like they were pretty much just shots in the dark.

Go Lang Handlers

```
package userhandlers

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    //"fmt"
    //"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    //"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"

    //Services
    databaseservice "malikiah.io/services/databaseService"
    passwordservice "malikiah.io/services/passwordService"

    //Structs
    userstructs "malikiah.io/structs/userStructs"
    databasestructs "malikiah.io/structs/databaseStructs"
)

func LoginHandler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    response.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    response.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    databaseQuery := databasestructs.Find{
        ID: bson.ObjectId(request.FormValue("_id")),
        MongoCollection: "users",
        Criteria: "_id",
        CriteriaValue: "",
        FindAll: false,
    }
    log.Println(databaseQuery)
    databaseservice.Login(databaseQuery)
}
```

Go Lang Structs

```
package databasestructs

import (
    //"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)

type Find struct {
    ID                      bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    MongoCollection         string              `json:"mongoCollection,omitempty" bson:"mongoCollection,omitempty"`
    Criteria                string              `json:"criteria,omitempty" bson:"criteria,omitempty"`
    CriteriaValue           string              `json:"criteriaValue,omitempty" bson:"criteriaValue,omitempty"`
    FindAll                 bool                `json:"findAll,omitempty" bson:"findAll,omitempty"`
}
```

Go Lang Functions

```
package databaseservice

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    //Structs
    userstructs "malikiah.io/structs/userStructs"
    databasestructs "malikiah.io/structs/databaseStructs"

    //"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"

)

func Find(databaseQuery databasestructs.Find) (result string) {
    // Set client options
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    // Database name
    db := client.Database("malikiah")
    collection := db.Collection(databaseQuery.MongoCollection)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if databaseQuery.Criteria == "_id" {
        log.Println(databaseQuery.ID)
        result := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{databaseQuery.Criteria: databaseQuery.ID}).Decode(&result)
        log.Println(result)
    } else if databaseQuery.Criteria == "" {

    } else if databaseQuery.FindAll == true {

    } else {

    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `labix.org/v2/mgo` is not maintained anymore, if you want to use `mgo`, use `github.com/globalsign/mgo` instead. Or the new, official [mongo-go driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver).

[`bson.ObjectId`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#ObjectId) is a type having `string` as its underlying type:

```
type ObjectId string
```

So when you fill your object like this:

```
databaseQuery := databasestructs.Find{
    ID: bson.ObjectId(request.FormValue("_id")),
    MongoCollection: "users",
    Criteria: "_id",
    CriteriaValue: "",
    FindAll: false,
}
```

`bson.ObjectId(request.FormValue("_id"))` is "nothing more" than a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). You convert the hex object ID string to `bson.ObjectId`, but this is **not** what you want. You want to *parse* the hex object ID. For that, use the [`bson.ObjectIdHex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#ObjectIdHex) **function**:

```
databaseQuery := databasestructs.Find{
    ID: bson.ObjectIdHex(request.FormValue("_id")),
    MongoCollection: "users",
    Criteria: "_id",
    CriteriaValue: "",
    FindAll: false,
}
```

Note that `bson.ObjectIdHex()` will panic if the passed string is an invalid hex object ID. Use [`bson.IsObjectIdHex()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#IsObjectIdHex) to check it prior to calling `bson.ObjectId()`. For details, see [Prevent runtime panic in bson.ObjectIdHex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701764/prevent-runtime-panic-in-bson-objectidhex/53701933#53701933).

If you would use the official driver instead of `mgo`, you could use [`primitive.ObjectIDFromHex()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectIDFromHex) function to create the `ObjectId`, e.g.:

```
id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(request.FormValue("_id"))
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    return
}
// If no error, you may use it:
databaseQuery := databasestructs.Find{
    ID: id,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So I was using primitive before and I switched because I saw everyone using this. but This is the issue I run into using the primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(request.FormValue("_id"))
```
multiple-value primitive.ObjectIDFromHex() in single-value context
```

Comment: @Malikiah See [Multiple values in single-value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227095/multiple-values-in-single-value-context/28233172#28233172). See edited answer.

Comment: Yeah, Think It needs to be like this
```
objectID, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(request.FormValue("_id"))
```

Comment: So now I am getting this error from my query result.... "cannot decode invalid into a string type" not sure what is happening now D:

Comment: @Malikiah I don't see your actual code now, but the one you posted in the question mixes `mgo` and `mongo-go` (the official driver). Be sure you don't do that.

Comment: I changed it to only use the import of "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive" and it now comes back as an ObjectID(), which is correct. but maybe I dont understand what I should be doing for the decoding of the mongodb document result on my Find function.

Comment: @Malikiah The problem seems to be that you try to decode into `result`, which is a `string`. Query returns documents, which may be decoded into `struct`s for example. You can't decode a document into a `string`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200603/discussion-between-malikiah-and-icza).

Comment: Any idea where I can get more information on decoding into this and what I can and cant decode to?

Comment: Are you saying I should make a struct and then decode this information to a specific struct?